# How to interact with SQL Server from xamarin through web service?

Tags: sql, asp.net, web-services, sql-server-2008, xamarin.android

I want to store data from Xamarin application to SQL Server through a web service. I tried to connect Xamarin Android with SQL Server via web service but failed.

Web:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=my-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=remotedb;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand com;

public Service1 () {

[WebMethod]
public string insert(string name)
{
    com = new SqlCommand("insert into dinesh values('" + name + "')", conn);
    conn.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Android:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    localhost.Service1 suresh = new localhost.Service1();
    string dinesh;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

        EditText e1 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);

        button.Click += delegate {
            dinesh = suresh.insert(e1.Text);
        };
    }
}
```

Is there anything I need to change or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is there anything i need to change."

Yes, almost everything.

Okay, let's start at the beginning.
If you've written an iPhone app which wants to talk to web services, it needs to be able to contact that URL.

Try opening Safari on your iPhone and connect to http://localhost/Service1.svc  (or wherever URL your services are stored).   Ah.  It can't find this URL.

You need your web services to be in the cloud somewhere, so your iPhone is able to connect to them.  Personally, I keep life easy and deploy my web services to Azure.

But then, your web services need to be able to talk to your SQL Server database... and again, your web services in the cloud aren't going to be able to find a server called "PC\SQLEXPRESS".   So you must also move your database into the cloud, and change your web service's ConnectionString to point at it.

Okay, once you've done all of that, you should have a URL to your web services which Safari can talk to.

From there, you can go into Xcode, and start writing code to talk to the services.

There's a load of decent tutorials out there which explain all of this, such as  [my C# / Xcode tutorial](http://www.mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm) which takes you through all of this, step by step.

Comment: Thanks Man , i am trying and  will let you know after that. :D